# ASP.Net MVC 5 - how to change raw html with html helper methods?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-5, html-helper

I have the following html code that I would like to change it to use html helper methods instead.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    <label>Date of Birth</label>
    <div class="input-group date" id="dtp">
        <input name="Birthday" id="txtBirthday" class="form-control" onfocus="$(this).next().trigger('click')" onkeydown="event.preventDefault()" />
        <span class="input-group-addon">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
        </span>
    </div>
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Birthday)
</div>
```

I want to change the above html code to the following using html helper methods but I don't know how to write `onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"` and `$(this).next().trigger('click')"` in the below code.

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Birthday)
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Birthday, new { @class = "form-control", id="txtBirthday" })    
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Birthday)
</div>
```

Comment: Use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` or if `EditorFor`, then the format is `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Birthday, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })`

Comment: @StephenMuecke I would like to use `@Html.TextBoxFor()` but how can I write `onkeydown="event.preventDefault()"` in it ?

Comment: Stop polluting your markup with behavior - use [Unobtrusive Javascript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) - `$('#Birthday').keydown(function(e) { ... });`

Comment: And `$(this).next().trigger('click')"` as an attribute makes no sense so not clear what your trying to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the onfocus and onkeydown to the same object where you added the `@class = "form-control`. As seen below

`@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Birthday, new { @class = "form-control", id="txtBirthday", onkeydown = "event.preventDefault()", onfocus = "$(this).next().trigger('click')" })`